# Could the metric of the universe have the following form?

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, universe

If the universe's metric had the following form

$$ds^{2}=N(r,\tau)c^{2}d\tau^{2}-a^{2}(\tau)\big(\frac{1}{1-kr^{2}}dr^{2}+r^{2}d\Omega^{2}\big)$$

for  $N(r,\tau)$, $N(\tau)$ or $N(r) \neq 1$. Would this metric somehow violate the cosmological principle or affect the world line of the fluid perfect?

Answer (score 4):

If $N(r, \tau)$ is a nontrivial function of $r$ (say, if $\partial_r N \neq 0$) then this metric violates homogeneity and isotropy: it implies that there is a specific dependence on the distance to some central point.

Note that the "usual" expression for the FRW metric is written in spherical coordinates for convenience (we are looking at the universe from basically a single point, after all), but it could be transformed to be centred at any other point, without changing at all.

If, on the other hand, $N(r, \tau) = N(\tau)$ (and $N$ is well-behaved) this is equivalent to FRW: just redefine the time coordinate so that $\mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{N} \mathrm{d}\tau$.
Since GR is invariant with respect to diffeomorphisms, this means that all physical predictions made with the two forms must coincide.

Comment: Thanks for your time